# xuggler video cut

Tags: java, video, video-processing, xuggler

I have two times (long time1, time2;), input file and output directory. i want to cut the video from time1 to time2 and save it in the outdir, can someone provide a simple expample of working code?

```
public class CutAndSaveVideoTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long timeStart=0, timeEnd=0;

        String filename = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\...\\File.avi"; 
        String outDir = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\...";
        String outFileName = "Test.mp4";
        String outDirFileName = (outDir +"\\" +outFileName );

        IContainer container = IContainer.make(); 


        if (container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " + filename);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything and/or have something incomplete to show?

Comment: added a little bit of code, but there is not much at all